# Is it usual to contract would (e.g. Adam'd) after proper nouns?

Tags: modal-verbs

I'm met with a tricky question, though not so essential I'd still like to know if places or peoples names can be joined by modal verbs.

I'm certain Adam **wouldn't** mind:

to Adam'd not mind.

Also I'd just like to clarify that it's to be used in a poetic context.

Thank you!

Comment: It's certainly acceptable verbally in certain dialects - pronounced "Adam'ud not mind" - but it's *never* acceptable in writing. It took me a moment to parse "Adam'd" and realise that it corresponded to a dialectical pronunciation of "Adam would", rather than an archaic spelling of the past participle (i.e. something like "Adammed").

Comment: There are a few written instances of [*I'd not mind if (blah blah)*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22I%27d+not+mind+if%22) in Google Books, but they're [dwarfed by ***I wouldn't mind if...***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I%27d+not+mind+if%2CI+wouldn%27t+mind+if&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CI%20would%20not%20mind%20if%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2CI%20would%20not%20mind%20if%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: Poetry doesn't follow the same conventions of grammar. You can pretty much write how you like.

Comment: Personally, I think it's alright if the name ends in a vowel. *Adam'd* is a little awkward.

Comment: @JasonBassford Thanks...for the answer I was expecting to hear. My day is made.